# Knockoutjs: Use Mapping and Validation plugin with complex view models

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I have a problem with the knockoutjs validation plugin and the mapping plugin.

I have the following view models:

```
var AthleteViewModel = function (json) {
    var self = this;

    // Instantiate the TrainZones like that: The input field is empty and it looks
    // like the property is not correctly bind but my Save() method shows "true"
    self.TrainZones = ko.validatedObservable(new TrainZonesViewModel(json.TrainZones));

    // Instantiate the TrainZones like that: The input field contains a value
    // and my validation is running but the Save() method don't run because an error
    // occurs that isValid() is not a function
    // self.TrainZones = new TrainZonesViewModel(json.TrainZones);

    self.Save = function () { alert(self.TrainZones.isValid()); };
};

var TrainZonesViewModel = function (json) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);

    self.RunningZone1Down.extend({ number: true });
    self.RunningZone1Up.extend({ number: true });
};
```

Now I instantiate the `AthleteViewModel` in my view:

```
var viewModel = {};

$(function () {
    viewModel = new AthleteViewModel(json);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

And bind a property to an input field:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: TrainZones.RunningZone1Down">
```

My Problem is, that with the line

```
self.TrainZones = ko.validatedObservable(new TrainZonesViewModel(json.TrainZones));
```

I have an empty input field but the `self.TrainZones.isValid()` shows `true`.

With the line

```
self.TrainZones = new TrainZonesViewModel(json.TrainZones);
```

the property binds correctly and the validation also runs for this field but there is no method `isValid()` in `self.TrainZones`.

How can I fix this problem, merge both solutions and get both functionalities? ;-)

Comment: I thought empty should be valid. You would need to make the field required for it to be invalid

Comment: I think it is important to know that my TrainZones.RunningZone1Down is filled and has assigned a value from my webservice. That meens the TrainZones.RunningZone1Down is never null or empty and the input field must show a value and must not be empty.

Comment: So you should use the required validation rule then and not just number.

Comment: The problem is not that my validations are not running, the problem is I haven't a `isValid()` function in my view model TrainZones.